# Scrollable ExtJS driven layout

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4

I'm working on project with heavy usage of ExtJS lib and so far as i'm not really good in pure CSS crossbrowser layout developing, i decide to use ExtJS layouts for robust markup prototyping. There is only one problem -- i can't figure out how to make my pages scrollable, like in traditional sites. ExtJS just clips any content overflowing browser viewport, "autoScroll: true" makes no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Based on the first ExtJS4 release and is no longer valid for newer versions***

It depends on your layout... A `viewport` should only contain one element and will also ignore scrollable settings. That's because the viewport use the `fit` layout by default. Give the scrollable setting to one item of the viewport that will contain all your content and remember, this one cannot be of the layout type fit.

```
{
   xtype: 'viewport',
   items: [{
      autoScoll: true // will be of xtype panel by default
      items: // you content
   }]
}
```

Comment: BTW, using `HBox` or `VBox` layouts can disable scrolling possibilities.

Comment: Viewports do not use the `fit` layout by default.  The default layout is `auto`.

Comment: This question is based on the first release of ExtJS4 an within that the viewport was set to fit as it was in ExtJS3. Or why do you think this was marked as answer?

Comment: Which release is that exactly then?  The current Ext release at the time 4.0.2a Ext.Viewport has the auto layout as the default as well as 3.4.  Maybe it was upvoted by fake accounts.  Here are some console outputs from the corresponding ext versions `'version' + Ext.getVersion().version + ' '+ new Ext.Viewport().layout.$className
>>"version4.0.2a Ext.layout.container.Auto"`    `'version: ' + Ext.version + ' ' + new Ext.Viewport().layout.type
>>"version: 3.4.0 auto"`

Comment: @sra just for good measure .. `'version' + Ext.getVersion().version + ' '+ new Ext.Viewport().layout.$className >>

"version4.0.0 Ext.layout.container.Auto" `